# Google AdMob No longer showing ads on Published Application

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I have published an application in Google Play Store and I used real App ID and after getting approved real ads was showing and running, however all of a sudden the ads stopped showing and I am getting 'Ad failed to load : 3'
I have found several answers saying that the code is correct but there might be an issue with the Account Google AdMob which I can seem to figure out. I was working on Android Studio using an Emulator to change some issues in the app and I have added the Ad ID of the emulator to the testing devices in Google AdMob as well. When I am using the Test ID and see them but when I use the actual App ID they dont show.

In my google Admob account I dont have any issues in the Policy Center which requires review. However when i first started the account I created 2 Apps one for Androis which is Ready and Approved and the other is Ios which is showing Requires Review as I have never published any apps on Ios yet but I had Ad Unit which I recently delete hoping that it could be the issue. I have notices the following message when I click on All APPs "Status Details: Limited ad serving Add store to lift limit"

My question could this be the reason why I no longer see real ads on the publish application?
If so how long until I see the ads back and if not how can I know what is the issue to fix it?

Comment: The correct place to post this would be: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/